# Facey McFaceface

Tags: code-golf, string

Anyone remember [Boaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boaty_McBoatface)?

You could totally make any old word, right?

- Write a function to turn a string into Somethingy McSomethingface.
- It should accept one string as input. Ignore the case of the input.
- If the word ends in 'y', your function should not add an additional 'y' to the first instance, but should remove it in the second instance.
- If the word ends in 'ey', it should not have an additional 'y' added in the first instance, but should remove both in the second instance.
- The output should only have upper case letters in the first character, the 'M' of 'Mc' and the first character after 'Mc'.
- it only needs to work with strings of 3 or more characters.

Examples:

```
boat                  =>  Boaty McBoatface
Face                  =>  Facey McFaceface
DOG                   =>  Dogy McDogface
Family                =>  Family McFamilface
Lady                  =>  Lady McLadface
Donkey                =>  Donkey McDonkface
Player                =>  Playery McPlayerface
yyy                   =>  Yyy McYyface
DJ Grand Master Flash =>  Dj grand master flashy McDj grand master flashface
```

Comment: What about spaces in the string, do we leave them intact?  Examples: ```'   y'``` and ```'      '```

Comment: I’m going to implement a suggestion from @Arnauld and make it three characters minimum. Treat whitespace just like another letter.

Comment: [Related: Code Johnny Code, Code!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/113276/code-johnny-code-code/)

Comment: Can we assume the input will only contain upper and lowercase letters?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I haven't put any non-letters in the test cases, so they're effectively not concerned.

Comment: @AJFaraday That's what I said... And regardless of what characters are in the test cases, you should clarify whether the input will contain non-letters, since a lot of commenters assume it may contain whitespace.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem Ahhh, good point. I've assumed whitespace is fine and that's been factored in to a lot of answers. I should have a test case for it. Probably `DJ Grand Master Flash => Dj grand master flashy McDj grand master flashface`

Comment: Donkey McDonkface is my favorite... seems like it would make a great insult.

Comment: This has to be the best function ever.

Comment: Nitpick: shouldn't that be Doggy McDogface?

Comment: @craq I thought of that, but too late, unfortunately. It’s hard to change it after people have answered.

Comment: Spaces in the input seem to break answers that rely on title-casing the input.

Comment: @Cowsquack if they pass my test cases, I declare them successful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 26 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ëO╛εh╕⌠î&!}∞┌C^U╟«äδ◙Bg⌠└¿
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=894fbeee68b8f48c26217decda435e55c7ae84eb0a4267f4c0a8&i=boat%0AFace%0ADOG%0AFamily%0ALady%0ADonkey%0A+ey%0Ayyy&a=1&m=2)

```
^           convert input to upper case                     "FACE"
B~          chop first character and push it back to input  70 "ACE"
v+          lowercase and concatenate                       "Face"
c'yb        copy, push "y", then copy both                  "Face" "Face" "y" "Face" "y"
:]          string ends with?                               "Face" "Face" "y" 0
T           trim this many character                        "Face" "Face" "y"
+           concatenate                                     "Face" "Facey"
p           output with no newline                          "Face"
"e?y$"z     push some strings                               "Face" "e?y$" ""
" Mc`Rface  execute string template; `R means regex replace " Mc Faceface"
            result is printed because string is unterminated
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%5E+++++++++%09convert+input+to+upper+case++++++++++++++++++++%09%22FACE%22%0AB%7E++++++++%09chop+first+character+and+push+it+back+to+input+%0970+%22ACE%22%0Av%2B++++++++%09lowercase+and+concatenate++++++++++++++++++++++%09%22Face%22%0Ac%27yb++++++%09copy,+push+%22y%22,+then+copy+both+++++++++++++++++%09%22Face%22+%22Face%22+%22y%22+%22Face%22+%22y%22%0A%3A]++++++++%09string+ends+with%3F++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%09%22Face%22+%22Face%22+%22y%22+0%0AT+++++++++%09trim+this+many+character+++++++++++++++++++++++%09%22Face%22+%22Face%22+%22y%22%0A%2B+++++++++%09concatenate++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%09%22Face%22+%22Facey%22%0Ap+++++++++%09output+with+no+newline+++++++++++++++++++++++++%09%22Face%22%0A%22e%3Fy%24%22z+++%09push+some+strings++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++%09%22Face%22+%22e%3Fy%24%22+%22%22%0A%22+Mc%60Rface&i=boat%0AFace%0ADOG%0AFamily%0ALady%0ADonkey%0A+ey%0Ayyy&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 15):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 27 <s>28</s> <s>30</s> bytes

```
Vu~Ùóe¿y$
Hóy$
ÁyJaMc<Esc>Aface
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P6y07vDMw5tTD@2vVOHyOLwZSB5urPRK9E2WdkxLTE79/z8tNTI5NRIA)

`<Esc>` represents `0x1b`

- Golfed two bytes after learning that we did not need to support inputs with less than 3 characters.
- 1 byte saved thanks to @DJMcMayhem by working on the second line before the first one, thus removing the `G`

The input is in the buffer. The program begins by converting everything to lowercase

`V` selects the line and `u` lowercases it

`~` toggles the case of the first character (converting it to uppercase)

and `Ù` duplicates this line above, leaving the cursor at the bottom line

`ó` and replaces `e¿y$`, compressed form of `e\?y$` (optional `e` and a `y` at the end of the line), with nothing (happens on the second line)

`H` goes to the first line

`ó` replaces `y$` (`y` at the end of the line) with nothing on the first line

`Á` appends a `y` to the end of the first line

`J` and joins the last line with the first with a space in the middle, and the cursor is moved to this space

`a` appends `Mc` (`<Esc>` returns to normal mode)

`A` finally, appends `face` at the end of the line

Comment: 27 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P6y07vDMw5tTD@2vVOHyOLwZSB5urPRK9E2WdkxLTE79/z8tNTI5NRIA "V – Try It Online")

Answer (score 13):

## Python, 144 bytes

```
def f(s):
 s=s[0].upper()+s[1:].lower()
 y=lambda s:s[:-1]if s[-1]=='y'else s
 t=y(s)
 u=s[:-2]if s[-2:]=='ey'else y(s)
 return t+'y Mc%sface'%u
```

[Try it online here](https://tio.run/##TY7LCsIwEEX3@YrZSFp8oF0Gsiu6UfyA0EVsJ1isScmkSL6@Nlofs5l7Lodh@hiuzhbj2KABk1EuGJAkta02Q9@jz/IlqZ2oNp17JGIQZafvl0YDCVJivataA6SmLSWPHDtCIAZBxukYg0EmqZilQiQLZ@1teAyDtxCWPMKpXpDRNfLFwJhxHgJSqPXkthYUg2n4xenAV@@8T@6cy/PhV9/bLn7oqJtvLp294ZfgL74mYSVeTe9bGzKTfT7I83F8Ag)

Comment: my first ever code golf attempt...

Comment: welcome to PPCG! might I suggest adding a link to [Try it Online!](https://tio.run/#python2) for verification of correctness?

Comment: `f("Face")` does not comply with the current test cases ([TIO](https://tio.run/##ZY4xT8MwEIX3/IqTpcq2WirKGCkLamFpxYwsD6a5QNTgoJw7@NeHu5RQqZ1envP5e/7J6auPT@NYYwONIVsWQBWtU5s6NLaAtgFyDxvfRqezXul37UsGXMlnBaTK0NLoDIfjgppwRL0wl398r8PIwhDrqwHZsNMeO0Iga9k/YDoPEZJ79PPoMrlN6cdAhEPiR6mPPiQFYKGqQD1zkT1JWVTFFXyRPoNSBJS8Bbdvr8z9gdv@UziOe99322U1@6RMQv64Rfehzv/TUhjkuBvu4wln46VM0/E0keMv)).

Comment: Edited post for correctness, also added a Try It Online! link

Comment: [136 bytes](https://tio.run/##Zc7BasMwDAbg@55CCEobysqao4Mvo2yXjT1AyMFtnG00jYPlMPT0meV26Uh8kX/88cs9hy/X5eNY2waaDWWKNJVP1W7oe@s32ZbKvap2rfuRVLBuzeVYGyCFjDrSx31luhqoVPHmPFARNMeeYpDHXFVao2X8M7mY9O5tGHwHYbtmeD@tqDEnu14NoyGyPsS/4NGZgACQgdaAzzGJlCkWH@7yRfIkJYmUOZeHj1eBN3lwnwLjWDZevlvGqVFSqoyXuX0zNd@3S4oyjsVu153t1HlNaXt3nlOw/O@bkBwsUDqMN3RNAtNJevwF).

Comment: [126 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY69DoJAEIR7nmIbcxB/EinPXGe00fgAhOKAvXgRD8IuxfnyyL9O9c3MTrK152fl4q7zqtTvrNBAkhK5P6bWCC@UoqRnLAmBggINmJAiGQApOuS6tqxL@8EwOrHyfXNq1bCOhzXO81hO@7FvkNvGAW@Fh3u@IaNzFJu2M1UDjMS57i@tgySAXiKrNIvdxJfhdObz4/qL37b0i7vpYuVz5V64OvjDUYNN5ZjUjXUcmnD5IIq6Lw)

Comment: [105 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY47DsIwEER7TuEGORYfiZSO0kXQgDhAlMIka2ER7MjeFObyxvnCVu/NTLGdx6fRaQgNSCITx7jL3bEWnULRqg8kLMPclfxwqpSknuZRIkPrgLisH6t0qGDuUj6VmFnA3mqCO@rJrd46KWqg2z5IYwmCw1rEmdKk3JB49GEE0v3E52E6c3G//OK3av1iV9GsXBj9gtXIH443aMXHpLNKYyKT5QPGwhc)

Comment: [97 bytes.](https://tio.run/##TY6xDoIwFEV3v6KLKY1oImNJN6KLxg9oOlRoYyMW0vcc6s9XQUDvdM7NzcvrI946X6TUGEtsBoyDgF2te4e6dS@TsRKFhBwk3@6VkjRSIUAOXAaDz@AJbmgk53oNVteGriWO42IYm2ldcKWS7QJBA1hrMMR5IlfkE3rtNNL8y4fhwsTV5firH66Ns510s3DV@btZjPzhmEEVH5s@OI@ZzeYPGEtv "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 12):

## Excel, <s>204</s> <s>144</s> <s>137</s> 165 bytes

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(REPT(REPLACE(LOWER(A1),1,1,UPPER(LEFT(A1)))&"~",2),"~","y Mc",1),"yy ","y "),"ey~","~"),"y~","~"),"~","face")
```

From the inside outwards:

```
REPLACE(LOWER(A1),1,1,UPPER(LEFT(A1)))      Replaces PROPER to handle space-delimited cases
REPT(%&"~",2)                   Duplicate.                    Donkey~Donkey~
SUBSTITUTE(%,"~","y Mc",1)      Replace first ~.              Donkeyy McDonkey~
SUBSTITUTE(%,"yy ","y ")        Handle words ending in 'y'.   Donkey McDonkey~
SUBSTITUTE(%,"ey~","~")         Handle words ending in 'ey'   Donkey McDonk~
SUBSTITUTE(%,"y~","~")          Handle words ending in 'y'    Donkey McDonk~
SUBSTITUTE(%,"~","face")        Adding face.                  Donkey McDonkface
```

---

Old answer, creating all bits separately, and then concatenating (176 bytes).
Does not handle space-delimited cases correctly.

```
=PROPER(A1)&IF(LOWER(RIGHT(A1,1))="y",,"y")&" Mc"&IF(LOWER(RIGHT(A1,2))="ey",LEFT(PROPER(A1),LEN(A1)-2),IF(LOWER(RIGHT(A1,1))="y",LEFT(PROPER(A1),LEN(A1)-1),PROPER(A1)))&"face"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, due to the requirement of handling space-delimited cases, `PROPER(A1)` is invalid (see the `DJ Grand Master Flash` input case), the best replacement that I could find while working on my VBA solution was `LEFT(UPPER(A1))&MID(LOWER(A1),2,LEN(A1))` - please let me know if you end up golfing that down.

Comment: Thank you @TaylorScott.  Found 'REPLACE(LOWER(A1),1,1,UPPER(LEFT(A1)))` which is 2 bytes shorter.

Answer (score 11):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>42</s> <s>37</s> 35 bytes

```
{S/y$//~"y Mc{S/e?y$//}face"}o&tclc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/Oli/UkVfv06pUsE3GchJtQdxa9MSk1OVavPVSpJzkv9bcxUnViqkaajEayqk5Rcp2CTlJ5YouAGVKLj4uwMZuZk5lQo@iSmVCi75edmplQoBOYmVqUV2/wE)

Answer (score 9):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>122</s> <s>108</s> <s>139</s> <s>175</s> <s>180</s> <s>179</s> 154 bytes

Thanks a lot, lee!

```cs
s=>((s.EndsWith("y")?s:s+"y")+" Mc"+(s+"$").Replace("ey$","")+"face").Replace(s,s.ToUpper()[0]+s.Substring(1).ToLower()).Replace("y$","").Replace("$","");
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVDRagIxEHy@@4ol@JDj7NG@arUPtQpFqdQWEfEhxqihZ3Jkc8oh9@3XjVewITCzO7AzjMQHaZ1qStTmAIsKvTr14yi8uCi3uZYgc4EIc2cPTpziaxz97dELT3C2egczoQ1P4ojU6CwcaFOUHgZg1GW9gSvbWuFZl42FVASjj8ltOOm8IjIVuwAja35UIPNcVMoRqarb/h0mTphgQukcjCnPkUEdYtIfl0Y@o3eUvwstDmFF3g0Ohpxj9mZ2uNT@yFnFkhfsYRpIymAmWcpp6rAk@1RFTuE4U1WHPIO@D2HvCnYx@7LfRaEcT9aPmxSzRbltDflTQtrUXoL279jfrfuinfsNUPA99S7kEXgoDKmytrUkaKHH6NUatLnKlk57NdWGMkAKrAeMYMUxSUIFdRwD1HHd/AI)

## C# (.NET Core, with LINQ), 152 bytes

```cs
s=>((s.Last()=='y'?s:s+"y")+" Mc"+(s+"$").Replace("ey$","")+"face").Replace(s,s.ToUpper()[0]+s.Substring(1).ToLower()).Replace("y$","").Replace("$","");
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVHfa8IwEH5u/oojCCbUle1VV/cwURiVyX4wRHyINWpZTbpcqxTxb@8uVtAQ@O7uI3dfvkvxIbVONxVmZgufNZZ6P2D3WZRk5m/AAn9YUa3yLIU0V4gwc3br1J6dWHCtY6lKgoPN1jBVmRGSBcQGB@UgM0VVQgxGHxdLOPGVVSXv8bFKNcHofXJJ9lleU5CotYeRNb/aB7Nc1dpRUNeX@htMnDJ@CEl0MCY9Ow5nL5PuuDLpM5aOPtGDFocwp9kNxkMhMEromZBx3K27L9jHkNdchhymKQ8FZR0uow9d5CRNcF13aKLnN17qjcEeRl/2uyi0E3LxuAwx@qxW7TjxJIlL7NFzd82uvW6FNh80QLI3tAiV7kB4u5AMaz2TnvMuBq/WoM119OOyUtNaSAOEwPvACeYCpfQGnBkDOLNz8w8)

Comment: Welcome to the site! :)

Answer (score 8):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>61</s> 49 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.capitalize=~/(e)?y$|$/;"#$`#$1y Mc#$`face"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcxBCsIwEEDRqwxJBF3Y4lpSN0U3igcQwTQmGFptMVNkTOLVY3bvb/577ihbmdeND77SanKoBvc18lcvzWpHIop6y7i4cbEhOOkiq7RhKS8@oRsVwr4ktOdDwdMNBEd1J2jHV28oVUbpB4SIEaYZPTAeMIFsgAd7wWsqmz8)

Saved 12 sweet bytes thanks to @MartinEnder:

- a slimmer regular expression, which made use of
- some of [Ruby's special global variables](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Special+global+variables) which I tend to forget, and
- bracketless string interpolation (see e.g. https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/52357/11071), which I never knew existed.

Comment: Using the regex from my Retina answer and making a bit more use of string interpolation gets this down to 49: https://tio.run/##DcxBCsIwEEDRqwxJBF3Y4lpSN0U3igcQwTQmGFptMVNkTOLVY3bvb/577ihbmdeND77SanKoBvc18lcvzWpHIop6y7i4cbEhOOkiq7RhKS8@oRsVwr4ktOdDwdMNBEd1J2jHV28oVUbpB4SIEaYZPTAeMIFsgAd7wWsqmz8

Comment: @MartinEnder Wow, that is quite a difference. I don't think I've seen string interpolation without brackets. I'll take it if you don't want to use it for your own Ruby answer.

Comment: Nah, it's fine, I wouldn't have come up with using `=~` and building the whole string instead of using `sub`. String interpolation can be used without brackets if the variable is a global, instance or class variable.

Comment: You can get this down to 44+1 bytes by using the `-p` flag and using `sub`: https://tio.run/##DchBCsIwEADA@74iQqAKavEFXkoLYtEHFHSTrhiMSUjSw4pvN@Y2TFwUlyJve43BZLTmQytIixLtmjZHll/ZbpvpwGLU0/2BmppSlMcMfTV0l6HibSzDGWeGzrsXMVwtMkVgrnMSQ0Q3ixFTpih6i@n58yEb71LZhT8

Answer (score 7):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGLOnline), 38 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
lW y≠F
u⁽³:F y*+pF‽j:lW e=⌡j}"‰θ`√►׀‘p
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=bFclMjB5JXUyMjYwRiUwQXUldTIwN0QlQjMlM0FGJTIweSorcEYldTIwM0RqJTNBbFclMjBlJTNEJXUyMzIxaiU3RCUyMiV1MjAzMCV1MDNCOCU2MCV1MjIxQSV1MjVCQSV1MDVDMCV1MjAxOHA_,inputs=Ym9hdA__,v=0.12)

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 80 bytes

Long time avid reader, my first submission at last !

```python
lambda y:re.sub("([\w ]+?)((e)?y)?$",r"\1\3y Mc\1face",y.capitalize())
import re
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##JYvBCsIwEETP@hVLEZpgEcSboL2Igih6FeNh26Y0mCZlE5H152urp3nDm@k4Nt6t@nqjeottUSHwmvQivAqRiLt6w2OeSyG0zFnmsySjRC3ViuFcqmWNpU4yXpTYmYjWfLSQcmrazlME0n3tCQIYB2nhMaYZpPvhMebucvjX1tjbSCes@Ce8e@ofXS2yppGY/@oIB0JXwRlD1AR7i6FJ19NJR8ZFEYaJipvtMK1FkLL/Ag)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, and very nice first post!

Answer (score 6):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 29 bytes

```
.+
$T
0`(e)?y$|$
$1y Mc$`face
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8F9Pm0slhMsgQSNV075SpUaFS8WwUsE3WSUhLTE59f//pPzEEi43IJPLxd8dyMjNzKnk8klMqeRyyc/LTq3kCshJrEwtAgA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>88</s> 92 bytes

```python
lambda s:(s+'y'*-~-(s[-1]in'yY')).title()+' Mc'+re.sub('e?y$','',s.title())+'face'
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYq7DoIwFIZneYozmJxWLomOJuhidNE4E2Ao0MZGaElbhy6@ei0ap//yfbN3D612QZRNGNnUDQzsntgUPW7yd05snW9bqdBXSGnhpBs5oSnCrcfU8MK@OoL86NeYIWb2L0RDsJ5jIqdZGweGB6ENWJAKauw0c5gBnhcl5ul@@c1JjtXSrmzwX6DVk3ts98lqNlI5sPFsXHmIUBBLwwc)

Comment: Fails with 'FamilY'

Comment: @Dead Possum: Fixed. Thks!

Answer (score 5):

## Java 8, <s>121</s> <s>112</s> <s>107</s> 106 bytes

```java
s->(s=(char)(s.charAt(0)&95)+s.toLowerCase().substring(1)).split("y$")[0]+"y Mc"+s.split("e?y$")[0]+"face"
```

-1 byte thanks to *@OliverGrégoire*.

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jU9NSwMxEL33VwxBJKE01IMHKVXEope2Cp6k9DCbTWvabLLsZCtB9rev2bp6kxUSkpl58z4OeMLJIT@2yiIRrNC4zxGAcUFXO1Qa1l0J8Boq4/ageP8hMUv9Jt10KGAwCtbgYA4tTW45zbl6x0pwkt17H/hUXN5cizHJ4Jf@Q1cPSJoLSXVGZ0Z@JVJVWhM4ixdMbKbbMYuwUizt9H199zvpvLF29q1f1plN@r2Nkzc5FClI73WzRdGHiBR0IX0dZJkmwTrupOIs8xiYOCf6G/TYKQ6BFs9P/yAqjI2DsCXmw6CFd0c9DHuxGHU1CItvP1TNqGm/AA)

```java
s->                         // Method with String as both parameter and return-type
  (s=                       //  Replace and return the input with:
     (char)(s.charAt(0)&95) //   The first character of the input as Uppercase
     +s.toLowerCase().substring(1))
                            //   + the rest as lowercase
  .split("y$")[0]           //  Remove single trailing "y" (if present)
  +"y Mc"                   //  Appended with "y Mc"
  +s.split("e?y$")[0]       //  Appended with the modified input, with "y" or "ey" removed
  +"face"                   //  Appended with "face"
```

Comment: What if the first char is not alphabetical? Or maybe we can get a rule added about that..

Comment: @streetster Just asked OP, and it seems the input will only contains uppercase and/or lowercase letters.

Comment: `~32` -> `95` for 1 byte saved

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I really need to start learning a bit more about bitwise operations.. >.>

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, <s>103</s> <s>96</s> 94 bytes

Pretty naïve first pass at this.

```
s=>(g=r=>s[0].toUpperCase()+s.slice(1).toLowerCase().split(r)[0])(/y$/)+`y Mc${g(/e?y$/)}face`
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##NYtBDoIwFESv4oJFG7DoAaoLiW4wrlwhya@lkGLpbyjRNMazVzBxNTPvZXrxFF6O2k1ri42KLY@e70jHR77z1aZmE16dU@NBeEVo6pk3WiqypbMo8fUXzDujJzLS@UJJHpKcphBWZ5m8O5Kr/QI@rZAKokTr0ShmsCMV3FFMkMFxURkUl9NvDNqEuZSiWaJA@1ABajYIR1rKetQWbhZo/AI)

Comment: s=>`${s=s[0].toUpperCase()+s.slice(1).toLowerCase().replace(/y$/,``)}y Mc${s.replace(/e?y$/,``)}face`

Comment: One less: s=>`${s=s[0].toUpperCase()+s.slice(1).toLowerCase().replace(/y$/,'')}y Mc${s.replace(/e$/,``)}face`

Comment: Thanks, @BenjaminGruenbaum, but the first fails for `Donkey` and the second for `Face`.

Comment: The markdown is ruining the code: https://gist.github.com/benjamingr/8fec077b5436846cc9c52be353238037

Comment: @Shaggy i managed to reduce the g function by some chars :). you can look in my solution

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, <s>47</s> 39 bytes

*Saved 6 bytes with @OlegV.Volkov's suggestions, 1 with @mwellnhof's, and 1 on my own*

```perl
$_=lc^$";$_=s/y?$/y Mc/r.s/e?y$//r.face
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3jYnOU5FyRrIKNavtFfRr1TwTdYv0ivWT7WvVNEHstISk1P//3dL9M3MSY38l19QkpmfV/xftwAA)

Comment: You can get rid of `ucfirst`: `$_=lc^$";`

Comment: `$_=s/y$//r."y Mc".s/e?y$//r.face` is one byte shorter.

Comment: `/y$|$/` -> `/y?$/`

Comment: Duh.  I should have realized that.

Answer (score 3):

## vim, <strike>35</strike> 34 bytes

```
Vu~Yp:s/ey$
:%s/y$
kgJiy Mc<ESC>Aface<ESC>
```

`<ESC>` is `0x1b`

#### Ungolfed

```
Vu~                      # Caseify McCaseface
Yp                       # dup line
:s/ey$ 
:%s/y$                   # Get the suffixes right
kgJiy Mc<ESC>Aface<ESC>  # Join lines and add the extra chars
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P6y0rrKywKpYP7VShctKtVgfSGWne2VWKvgmSzumJSanSv//n5SfWAIA)

Saved 1 byte thanks to DJMcMayhem

Comment: You can do `Y` instead of `yy`

Answer (score 3):

## C++ 14 (g++), <s>181</s> <s>171</s> <s>148</s> <s>147</s> 134 bytes

```c++
[](auto s){s[0]&=95;int i=1,b;for(;s[i];)s[i++]|=32;b=s[--i]-'y';return s+(b?"y":"")+" Mc"+(b?s:s.substr(0,s[i-1]-'e'?i:i-1))+"face";}
```

Note that clang will not compile this.

Credit goes to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/160529/79343) and [Olivier Grégoire](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16236/olivier-gr%C3%A9goire) for the `&95` trick.

Thanks to [Chris](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58834/chris) for golfing 11 bytes.

Try it online [here](https://tio.run/##dY9Ra4MwFIWf568IGayKdbQbe5ip68tooax0705KjGkXprEk8UG6/naXxDIGS16813P8zrmS0yk5EjLgTrWgARkY8iK0LzI6y3xW3GXPT4hxBVg2n5bo0IoQyZwVKNLPOC6@s8cHVGYyTxJWJJN@ggRVneBAxmG5hD1MIYxiCLYEGkGm8l52pVQinE11QjLXEJ0sWarXSH94wIRCdBlQENwyTuquomDBWg1Q3LwEDWY8jMA5uJGqSlMtM34EZYuVvh2aCdHVI22nwGIBmtDIkVnhB/@1r@hK9xl0ZXv/oUb2oa@7tSH1cIBa9Vc2rO7HUrM5a43hC3jDlcXNdMBG9t7c8i9q4XFzXW4NX8B7jXsqTMC4OQJGwxfQ97ZeDweqVe/lm/1aYF7tt1gqKvarGstP@yMbYA0wGsAarv9yBfxpuww/).

Ungolfed version:

```c++
[] (auto s) { // lambda taking an std::string as argument and returning an std::string
    s[0] &= 95; // convert the first character to upper case
    int i = 1, // for iterating over the string
    b; // we'll need this later
    for(; s[i] ;) // iterate over the rest of the string
        s[i++] |= 32; // converting it to lower case
    // i is now s.length()
    b = s[--i] - 'y'; // whether the last character is not a 'y'
    // i is now s.length()-1
    return s + (b ? "y" : "") // append 'y' if not already present
    + " Mc"
    + (b ? s : s.substr(0, s[i-1] - 'e' ? i : i-1)) // remove one, two, or zero chars from the end depending on b and whether the second to last character is 'e'
    + "face";
}
```

Comment: I don't know C++ that well, but you can golf 9 bytes: [Try it online **172 bytes.**](https://tinyurl.com/ybo5uhr5) Summary of changes: `s[0]=s[0]&~32;` to `s[0]&=~32;`; `s[i++]=s[i]|32;` to `s[i++]|=32`; and `int i=1,n=s.length()-1,b;` so you only need 1 `int`.

Comment: Oh, and one more byte by removing the space at `#include<string>`

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks for catching that! I have edited.

Comment: You can save 11 bytes by not defining `n` and just using the value of `i` after the while loop. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY9RS8MwFIWf7a@4RHAt3WSb@GCzuhfZYDj0fZaRptkMtulI0ocy99trkg4RTF967z2n3z039HSaHCntSKNrqCCFbpeFblDRWe2m2V369Ii50MDT2TjHh1qGWO14hiPzjePsO32Y4zw1w2SWTUbtCEumGylAxWG@RC1KEIpiBFuKrKASda@aXGkZTscWmhuIjZaGTswQmV8PhDKELx0OglsuaNkUDBa8Nggj1XNQES7CCM7BjdJFkhiZiyPkNdHmemQrwleP1o2GxQKq0MqRbdGH@LWv6MrkWXTlcv@hVh5CX97WljTFAxp1OLLiZduH2s4ba42hBa@kcLitHtjKgzfX4os5uO98lztjaMF7SVom7YK@8yzojaEFbeviTfGgRh28fLNfSyKK/ZYozeR@VRL16R6yAWdAb4AzfO/yLfiTdul@AA)

Comment: @Chris Thanks! I managed to shave off 2 more bytes.

Comment: [129 bytes](https://tio.run/##dY9RS8MwFIWf7a8IEVxKV9kUH1wWfZENhkPfaxlpms1gm44kfShzv70m6RDB9KX39px@59yy4zE9MNbT1jSgBgT0WY78i45PQhogyHxa4H2jkM5m@Q15fMA6EzmO7TNJ8m9yf4cLorM0FTkhk26CFTetkkAnCHYwKeIEgi2DCSqe9a1uC20Umk1FahmRzh3DJ/FC28/2lHGIzz2OomshWdWWHCxFYwFO66eopkKiGJyiK23KxcLKQh5A0VBjz4ZuQnzxWNMasFyCGjk5div8kL/2BV3ZPoeufO8/1Mlj6Mvb2pF2BECrjlfWouqGUrcFa50xFvBKS4@7GYCdPHpzI7@4h4ctdLk3xgLeK9px5QKGLRAwGGMBXefr7QigVh29fLNbKyrL3ZZqw9VuVVH96X9kA7wBBgN4I/RfoYA/bef@Bw "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/), <s>112</s> <s>110</s> <s>107</s> 106 bytes

*now as short as java*

```
fn x->x=String.capitalize x;"#{x<>if x=~~r/y$/,do: "",else: "y"} Mc#{String.replace x,~r/e?y$/,""}face"end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY89D4IwEIZ3fsXlcICEj10RF6Ix0TA4GocCV9NYW1IYiop/HSlxet5cnsvdS1JYYSauDSjIYrhipVmPESBnNTkW5cFhz55CDi6dWLOw0OpBA96g0V4wcQU2zu320huh7knNWtEzKV4EdoP@22a54GC3369Jh1UaNXoNiBHJjuYw4Ajn2n//lw21cr4ONppt2jkfcVweItVMYRKo0PvkcCwTobqW6j6QrCK5hnnuDNfhBw)

Explanation:

```
x=String.capitalize x
```

Gets `x` with the first character in uppercase and all others lowercase.

```
#{ code }
```

Evaluate the code and insert it into the string.

```
#{x<>if x=~ ~r/y$/, do: "", else: "y"}
```

Concatenates **x** with `y` if it does not end with `y` (ie it does not match the regex `y$`).

```
#{String.replace x, ~r/e?y$/, "")}
```

Removes trailing `ey` and trailing `y`.

Answer (score 2):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>38</s> <s>36</s> 32 bytes

-5 byte thanks to @Cows quack

```
Vu~hy$ó[^y]$/&y
A Mc<esc>póe¿y$
Aface
```

`<esc>` is a literal escape character and `[^` is encoded as `\x84`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P6y0LqNS5fDm6LjKWBV9tUouRwXfZJvU4mS7gsObUw/tr1ThckxLTE79/x9EVv7XLQMA)

Comment: `gu$` can become `Vu`

Comment: Since `[^` is a regex shortcut (see [here](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V/wiki/Regexes#shortcuts)), you can use 0x84 instead of `[^` to save a byte. Similarly, `\?` can be simplified into `<M-?>` to save another byte. And `$a` => `A`

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 69 bytes

```ruby
->s{"#{(s.capitalize!||s)[-1]==?y?s:s+?y} Mc#{s.gsub /e?y$/,""}face"}
```

Explanation:

```ruby
->s{                                                                } # lambda 
    "#{                                 } Mc#{                }face" # string interpolation
       (s.capitalize!||s) # returns string capitalized or nil, in that case just use the original string
                         [-1]==?y # if the last character == character literal for y
                                 ?s:s+?y # then s, else s + "y"
                                              s.gsub /e?y$/,"" # global substitute
                                                               # remove "ey" from end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfpmCrEPNf1664Wkm5WqNYLzmxILMkMSezKlWxpqZYM1rXMNbW1r7SvtiqWNu@slbBN1m5ulgvvbg0SUE/1b5SRV9HSak2LTE5Van2f0FpSbFCWnR6aklx7H@X/Lzs1EoA)

Comment: Could you add a TIO link? I don't know Ruby, but does `s.capitalize` replace the previous `s`? If not, does `/e?y$/` handle a test case ending in `Y`, `EY`, or `Ey` correctly?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen `s.capitalize` vs `s.capitalize!` (different functions). `s.capitalize!` clobbers the old version.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I've added a TIO link.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Also added an explanation

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the explanation and the information about `s.capitalize!`. Never programmed in Ruby, but adding an explanation mark to replace the previous value is pretty cool. +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>117</s> 114 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to Dead Possum*

```python
def f(s):s=s.title();return s+'y'*(s[-1]!='y')+' Mc'+([s,s[:-1],0,s[:-2]][(s[-1]=='y')+((s[-2:]=='ey')*2)])+'face'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzBDoIwEETvfMV6agtoFG81vRG9aPyApjEIbWzEQtj1wNdjgcS9zLzd2elHenXhOE2NdeA4CokKd@SptVycBkvfIQBmbGQpR709mI2KXmQMbjXLuMYctYzrfL@Ywhi95tSa4zMVckYbOS2Eic@uqi2byCI96gotKNDs2VXEcmDn@Ra1vF9W/Ph2nN21ahYtu/COXSZx3QAefIB/kUwgTj/4QNxxL8T0Aw)

Comment: 3rd element of list `[s,s[:-1],'',s[:-2]` can be changed to `0` to save 1 byte.

Comment: In `'y'*1`  `*1` is not needed. 2 more bytes

Comment: Switching from Python 3 to Python 2, and replacing `return` with `print` is 1 byte shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## [K4](http://kx.com/download/), <s>74</s> <s>69</s> 68 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{$[r;x;x,"y"]," Mc",_[r:0&1-2/:"ye"=2#|x;x:@[_x;0;.q.upper]],"face"}
```

**Examples:**

```
q)k)f:{$[r;x;x,"y"]," Mc",_[r:0&1-2/:"ye"=2#|x;x:@[_x;0;.q.upper]],"face"}
q)f each ("boat";"Face";"DOG";"Family";"Lady";"Donkey";"Player")
"Boaty McBoatface"
"Facey McFaceface"
"Dogy McDogface"
"Family McFamilface"
"Lady McLadface"
"Donkey McDonkface"
"Playery McPlayerface"
```

**Explanation:**

Figure out if the last characters are equal to `"ey"`, convert result to base-2 so we can ignore words that end `"e?"`. Index into a list of numbers of characters to trim.

Managed to shave 5 bytes off my code to determine whether the last two chars at `"ey"` but struggling to better it...

```
{$[r;x;x,"y"]," Mc",_[r:0&1-2/:"ye"=2#|x;x:@[_x;0;.q.upper]],"face"} / the solution
{                                                                  } / lambda function
                                                            ,"face"  / join with "face"
                    _[                  ;                  ]         / cut function
                                           @[_x; ;        ]          / apply (@) to lowercased input
                                                0                    / at index 0
                                                  .q.upper           / uppercase function
                                         x:                          / save back into x
                                      |x                             / reverse x
                                    2#                               / take first two chars of x
                               "ye"=                                 / equal to "ye"?
                             2/:                                     / convert to base 2
                           1-                                        / subtract from 1
                         0&                                          / and with 0 (take min)
                       r:                                            / save as r
             ," Mc",                                                 / join with " Mc"
 $[r;x;x,"y"]                                                        / join with x (add "y" if required)
```

**Bonus:**

**67 byte** port in [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok):

```
{$[r;x;x,"y"]," Mc",((r:0&1-2/"ye"=2#|x)_x:@[_x;0;`c$-32+]),"face"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v1olusi6wrpCR6lSKVZHScE3WUlHQ6PIykDNUNdIX6kyVcnWSLmmQjO@wsohOr7C2sA6IVlF19hIO1ZTRyktMTlVqVbJJT8vO7VS6f9/AA)

Comment: What's the point in the K4 if your oK port defeats it?

Comment: I didn't think it would, and the port doesn't work if the first char isn't alphabetical as I blindly subtract 32 from the ASCII value - there's no "upper" built-in.

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <strike>143</strike> 142 bytes

```
func[s][s: lowercase s s/1: uppercase s/1
w: copy s if"y"<> last s[append w"y"]rejoin[w" Mc"parse s[collect keep to[opt["y"|"ey"]end]]"face"]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYuxDsIgFEX3fsXL@4Gma2OcjC4ajSthQHgkVQQCNITEf0c6qHU859wbSNUrKWC802PVs5UschZHMC5TkCISRIj9MMLs/Uf0Q5dHkM6XFieNBTdbMCImiEy0mVWQm@SB7m6yLCOcJHoRli@TzhiSCR5EHpJjzifWxi@k9mhXzlELSch59WGyCTTgzYmE3Rf3S//h7nz4i8/JlJU4CrVG5eyD1uJiRKGA9Q0)

Ungolfed:

```
f: func[s][
   s: lowercase s                      ; make the entire string lowercase
   s/1: uppercase s/1                  ; raise only its first symbol to uppercase 
   w: copy s                           ; save a copy of it to w
   if "y" <> last s[append w "y"]     ; append 'y' to w if it doesn't have one at its end
   rejoin[w                            ; assemble the result by joining:
          " Mc"
          ; keep the string until "y", "ey" or its end
          parse s[collect keep to [opt ["y" | "ey"] end]]
          "face"
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 30 bytes

```
™D'y©Ü®«s¤®Qi¨¤'eQi¨]’McÿŠÑ’ðý
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UcsiF/XKQysPzzm07tDq4kNLDq0LzDy04tAS9VQQHfuoYaZv8uH9RxccnghkHt5weO///y75edmplQA)
or as a [Test suite](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9TVvn/UcsiF/XKQysPzzm07tDq4kNLDq0LzDy04tAS9VQQXVv7qGGmb/Lh/UcXHJ4IZB7ecHjv/0qlw/sVdO0UDu9X0vmflJ9YwuWWmJzK5eLvDmTkZuZUcvkkplRyueTnZadWcgXkJFamFgEA)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 87 bytes

- thanks to @Shaggy for 5 reducing 5 bytes

```javascript
s=>(g=r=>Buffer(s.replace(r,"")).map((x,i)=>i?x|32:x&~32))(/y$/)+`y Mc${g(/e?y$/)}face`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY7NasMwEITvfQohQpFoakNyK8iBEBIoDe01t6i25DqRLSO5xaI/r@5q5TiHYJ92dvebYU78i9vUFHXzWOlMdJJ1liUkZ4Yl608phSE2MqJWPBXEzDGmNCp5TUg7LyhLilX7s1w8tfd/ywWlJHazmD4cHdqns@@cxGIFh1/pzccu1ZXVSkRK50QS/K55gyliDOG1l@CBCSymdzfwNlwDDBJgmOPw5nV3YTc6B9SPqdiyUO4aDEtI9mLc8MKzAQfpYT8mWujqLNy1CCyhSnUe598Ud8Jc@H4BQ6/GLc4N@QcH7MFNVHlGO8OrDO25bYRBW8Xtx9DshPLwK/ufhF9oOvbo87t/)

Comment: You don't have to name non-recursive functions.

Comment: Nicely done. I never think to use `Buffer`, will have to try to remember it for future challenges. Got it down to [87 bytes](https://tio.run/##dY7NasMwEITvfQohQpFoakNyK8iBEBIoDe01t6i25DqRLSO5xaI/r@5q5TiHYJ92dvebYU78i9vUFHXzWOlMdJJ1liUkZ4Yl608phSE2MqJWPBXEzDGmNCp5TUg7LyhLilX7s1w8tfd/ywWlJHazmD4cHdqns@@cxGIFh1/pzccu1ZXVSkRK50QS/K55gyliDOG1l@CBCSymdzfwNlwDDBJgmOPw5nV3YTc6B9SPqdiyUO4aDEtI9mLc8MKzAQfpYT8mWujqLNy1CCyhSnUe598Ud8Jc@H4BQ6/GLc4N@QcH7MFNVHlGO8OrDO25bYRBW8Xtx9DshPLwK/ufhF9oOvbo87t/) for you.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jstx](https://github.com/Quantum64/Jstx), 27 [bytes](https://quantum64.github.io/Jstx/codepage)

```
h</►yT↓►y/◙♂ Mc♀/◄eyg►yg/íå
```

Explanation

```
      # Command line args are automatically loaded onto the stack
h     # Title case the top of the stack
<     # Duplicate the top value on the stack twice
/     # Print the top value on the stack
►y    # Load 'y' onto the stack
T     # Returns true if the 2nd element on the stack ends with the top
↓     # Execute block if the top of the stack is false
  ►y  # Load 'y' onto the stack
  /   # Print the top value on the stack
◙     # End the conditional block
♂ Mc♀ # Load ' Mc' onto the stack
/     # Print the top value on the stack
◄ey   # Load 'ey' onto the stack
g     # Delete the top of the stack from the end of the 2nd element on the stack if it exists
►y    # Load 'y' onto the stack
g     # Delete the top of the stack from the end of the 2nd element on the stack if it exists
/     # Print the top of the stack
íå    # Load 'face' onto the stack
      # Print with newline is implied as the program exits
```

[Try it online!](https://quantum64.github.io/Jstx/JstxGWT-1.0.1/JstxGWT.html?code=aDwv4pa6eVTihpPilrp5L%24KXmeKZgiBNY%24KZgC_il4RleWfilrp5Zy_DrcOl&args=Ym9hdA%3D%3D)

Comment: I haven't seen this language before.  It looks interesting.  Is there documentation?

Comment: @recursive [Here's some documentation.](https://quantum64.github.io/Jstx/JstxGWT-1.0.2/JstxGWT.html?mode=ref)

Comment: Wow, this is really impressive.  Especially for so little development time.  I'm excited to see where this goes.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP: 132

```
<?php function f($s){$s=ucfirst(strtolower($s));return $s.(substr($s,-1)=='y'?'':'y').' Mc'.preg_replace('/(ey|y)$/','',$s).'face';}
```

### Explanation:

```
<?php

function f($s)
{
    // Take the string, make it all lowercase, then make the first character uppercase
    $s = ucfirst(strtolower($s));

    // Return the string, followed by a 'y' if not already at the end, then ' Mc'
    // and the string again (this time, removing 'y' or 'ey' at the end), then
    // finally tacking on 'face'.
    return $s
        . (substr($s, -1) == 'y' ? '' : 'y')
        . ' Mc'
        . preg_replace('/(ey|y)$/', '', $s)
        . 'face';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <del>36</del> 34 bytes

```
++Jrz4*\yqJK:J"e?y$"k+" Mc"+K"face
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2B%2BJrz3%2a%5CyqJK%3AJ%22%28e%29%3Fy%24%22k%2B%22+Mc%22%2BK%22face&input=donkey&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=boat%0AFace%0ADOG%0AFamily%0ALady%0ADonkey%0APlayer%0Ayyy%0ADJ+Grand+Master+Flash&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
++Jrz4*\yqJK:J"(e)?y$"k+" Mc"+K"face

  Jrz4                                  Set J to the titlecase of z (input)
           K:J"e?y$"k                   Set K to (replace all matches of the regex e?y$ in J with k (empty string))
         qJ                             Compare if equal to J
      *\y                               Multiply by "y" (if True, aka if no matches, this gives "y", else it gives "")
 +                                      Concatenate (with J)
                             +K"face    Concatenate K with "face"
                       +" Mc"           Concatenate " Mc" with that
+                                       Concatenate
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work, as the last test case fails.

Comment: Switch `rz3` to `rz4` to get this to work properly for the last test case.

Comment: Oh whoops, I'll fix that :P

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>77</s> <s>75</s> <s>74</s> 73 bytes

```
2ḶNṫ@€⁼"“y“ey”S
ØA;"ØaF
¢y⁸µ¢Uyµ1¦
Çṫ0n”yẋ@”y;@Ç;“ Mc”
⁸JU>ÑTị3Ŀ;@Ç;“face
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/o4Y5tfg93rnZ41LTmUeMepUcNcyqBOBVIzA3mOjzD0Vrp8IxEN65DiyofNe44tPXQotDKQ1sNDy3jOtwO1GaQB1RX@XBXtwOItnY43G4N1K3gmwzkcgE1eIXaHZ4Y8nB3t/GR/TDZtMTk1P///6s75SeWqAMA)

Any golfing suggestions are welcome (and wanted)!

Answer (score 1):

## Python, <s>105</s> 104

```
import re;r=re.sub;c=str.capitalize;f=lambda s:r('([^e^y])$','\\1y',c(s))+' Mc'+r('ey$','',c(s))+'face'
```

thx @Berry M. from noticing my dyslexia

Comment: -1 byte if you spell `Mc` correctly!

Answer (score 1):

### Pyth, <s>60</s> 59 bytes<sup>SBCS</sup>

```
K"ey"Jrz4Iq>2JK=<2J=kK.?=k\yIqeJk=<1J))%." s÷   WZÞàQ"[JkJ
```

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=K%22ey%22Jrz4Iq%3E2JK%3D%3C2J%3DkK.%3F%3Dk%5CyIqeJk%3D%3C1J%29%29%25.%22+s%C2%9C%C2%82%C2%8C%C3%B7%09WZ%C3%9E%C3%A0Q%22%5BJkJ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=boat%0AFace%0ADOG%0AFamily%0ALady%0ADonkey%0APlayer%0Ayyy%0ADJ+Grand+Master+Flash&debug=0)

They don't display here, but three bytes, `\x9c`, `\x82`, and `\x8c` are in the packed string between `s` and `÷`. Rest assured, the link includes them.

Python 3 translation:

```
K="ey"
J=input().capitalize()
if J[-2:]==K:
    J=J[:-2]
    k=K
else:
    k="y"
    if J[-1]==k:
        J=J[:-1]
print("{}{} Mc{}face".format(J,k,J))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>95</s> <s>90</s> <s>88</s> <s>87</s> <s>86</s> <s>85</s> <s>84</s> <s>82</s> <s>80</s> <s>78</s> <s>77</s> 73 bytes

```apl
{'face',⍨(' Mc',S↓⍨-+/∧/¨Y'ey'=¨↑∘S¨-⍳2),⍨S,(Y≠⊃⌽S←⍵(819⌶¨)⍨1=⍳⍴⍵)/Y←'y'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@/Wj0tMTlVXedR7woNdQXfZHWd4Edtk4E8XW39Rx3L9Q@tiFRPrVS3PbTiUdvERx0zgg@t0H3Uu9lIE6QjWEcj8lHngkddzY969gL1TXjUu1XDwtDyUc@2Qys0gQoMbYFqH/VuAYpr6kcCFahXqtf@dwMyBsBerupHfVOBbDcFoHDtoRXqSfmJJeoK6m4ghyiou/i7gzm5mTmVQIZPYgqIcsnPy04FMQJyEitTi4CMykqwuJeCe1FiXoqCb2JxSWqRghswQDPU/wMA)

This could be golfed down some more, and any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 45  <s>46</s> bytes

```php
<?=($s=ucfirst(fgets(STDIN)))."y Mc{$s}face";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt5WQ6XYtjQ5LbOouEQjLT21pFgjOMTF009TU1NPqVLBN7lapbg2LTE5Vcne7v//5MSS/yn56QA)

Comment: Fails in two different ways with input `boAty`. (Wrong caps, 'y' not removed).

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure: <s>161</s> 155

```
(use '[clojure.string :as s])
(defn f[t](s/join[(s/capitalize(cond(=(last t)\y)t :else(s/join[t "y"])))" Mc"(s/capitalize(s/replace t #"e*y$" ""))"face"]))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(defn facegen [s0]
  (let [ s1 (clojure.string/capitalize (cond
                                         (= (last s0) \y)  s0
                                         :else             (clojure.string/join [s0 "y"])))
         s2 (clojure.string/capitalize (clojure.string/replace s0 #"e*y$" ""))]
    (clojure.string/join [s1 " Mc" s2 "face"])))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY4xCsMwDEX3nEKohUodmj3QI/QEaQbjyMXBOCFShvTyrkvo0OnzP@/B92metlVKoU0FLr0/@k1tjfkFnVPQgRsaJWQIvQ2k7TTH3Nf0bonmUnwL@TmPdKfk1MD4ubNBJ0nlRxvgjgMzIzw8/rvarrIk5wUMTijX/YyAWNFQt6/UNLTUN5YyUIBjZi7lAw)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 62 bytes

```apl
{'face',⍨(' Mc','e?y$'⎕r''⊢S),⍨S,(Y≠⊃⌽S←⍵(819⌶¨)⍨1=⍳⍴⍵)/Y←'y'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@/Wj0tMTlVXedR7woNdQXfZHUd9VT7ShX1R31Ti9TVH3UtCtYEyQXraEQ@6lzwqKv5Uc/e4EdtEx71btWwMLR81LPt0ApNoAJD20e9mx/1bgGKa@pHAhWoV6rX/ncDMmhqA1c10Bgg200BKFx7aIV6Un5iibqCuhvISgV1F393MCc3M6cSyPBJTAFRLvl52akgRkBOYmVqEZBRWQkW91JwL0rMS1HwTSwuSS1ScAMGUob6fwA)

Thanks to @ngn for this solution!

Answer (score 1):

**Unix** (**79 bytes**)

Using Standard input :

```
 rev|sed -r 's/(.*)(.)$/\L\1\U\2/;s/^(ye?)?(.*)$/ecaF\2cM y\1\2/;s/ yy/ y/'|rev
```

test :

```
echo -e "Lady\nFace\nDonkey\nyyy"|rev|sed -r 's/(.*)(.)$/\L\1\U\2/;s/^(ye?)?(.*)$/ecaF\2cM y\1\2/;s/ yy/ y/'|rev
Lady McLadFace
Facey McFaceFace
Donkey McDonkFace
Yyy McYyFace
```

or ( by Function) :

```
F(){ echo $1|rev|sed -r 's/(.*)(.)$/\L\1\U\2/;s/^(ye?)?(.*)$/ecaF\2cM y\1\2/;s/ yy/ y/'|rev;}
```

test :

```
 F donkey
 Donkey McDonkFace
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 98 bytes

```powershell
(("y$","e?(?=y)y$"|%{$o.ToUpper()[0]+$o.ToLower().Substring(1)-replace $_,""})-join "y Mc")+"face"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVNRa9swEH6uf8UhXJBIHJo9poSOraTbaFihKaWEMFRXSdw6kicpDOH6t6d3cuq@9GF@uk93933f6ZAq809Zt1VlmeXGqsNsr3NfGA0L5TwXSZ2cpB6hgyl85eK8Ow6msLwNzqvdaLGvSrWaTL5bJb3i7NFIz4bsG4YA85ziWuaK/R97Rq3DGIhNsQf78vcVki/NhrgYehnvijJEawLRG0EPhWv5RHwKyMbQZ3CjX1SIsxOI0@uXHgI3pQzKokALSKFFPTRCoAkeApEfQp/pf8GVlfoJ5hLrFmaldFu6zDNsYn7X5teUj5f7rNAZdpavcAr4BE9SJ3foiI8w/TP6iROMzykrtcPn@5H9ErNW@b3VmJ0ZA0cmFahWuLn0@ZYox7YsV3/hqERd97bwKvthnAfOuv4sg/qsgZbjoB43LFu/iw/fxQQ0SZMk3SfCAfjSeVvozSo1oj5w3HGKe1EX/GIaBOLX0zo1o4W5qypluVierQbxfE0fk4vR7f6xFeBjkVlVlbgjvO6QsUZkz6bQwGifTAxYXN8B/envHt4A)

Many thanks to [@Anderson Pimentel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/160568/68634) for inspiring a solution using regex replacements!

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 134 bytes

An anonymous VBE Immediate Window Function that takes input from range [A1] and outputs to the Immediate Window.

```
b=[Left(Upper(A1))]+Mid([Lower(A1)],2):l=len(b):y=[Right(A1)="y"]:?b;IIf(y,"","y")" Mc"IIf(y,Left(b,l-1+(InStrRev(b,"e")=l-1)),b)"face
```